# scrollTop() smooth animation on nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I scroll I want my nav size to decrease from 90px to 68px, I've been working with jquery `.css` and it works but its not as smooth as I want and I think I should use `animate()` but honestly I dont know how, I googled but couldn't find anything so any help ?

```js
function totop(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
                $('#nav').css({'height':'68px'});
            } else {
                $('#nav').css({'height':'90px'});
            }
        });
    }
    totop();
```

```css
#nav {
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(44, 44, 44),rgba(29, 38, 51, 0.5) 50px);
    position: fixed;
    transition: .3s;
    z-index: 12312312312312;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 200vh">
<div id="nav">
  <h2 class="logo"><span>Levan</span><br>Charuashvili</h2>
  <ul class="windows">
      <li>
          <a href="#">Prices</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="about" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t think you should use animate … instead, specify a different transition duration for the height property, if the current one of `.3s` applied to _all_ changing properties isn’t long enough for the “smoothness” you want.

Comment: Honestly, what is not 'smooth' about it? I experience a fluent transition from 90px to 68px and vice versa.

Comment: @Bram I want even more smoother